# Retrieve argument from a git pre-commit hooks with python

Tags: python-3.x, git, githooks

I am strating on git hooks really, and i want to make python hooks since my project is already in python.

I grasp the concept if trigger but i can't retrieve arguments. I followed multiple documentation but I keep circling around.

```
import sys


def main():
    print("Number of arguments: %d", len(sys.argv))
    print("Argument List: %s" % str(sys.argv))

sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried both the 3.9 and 3.6 python interpreter and i've seen people getting argument on a video posted a year ago.

The result of my `commit -a -m "test"` is `Number of arguments: %d 1; Argument List: ['.git/hooks/pre-commit']`

From what i know about python argument, `sys.argv[0]` should always be the name of the executable and anything after should be the argument.

I tried both commiting through gitDesktop at first but then with gitBash, but correctly stop at `sys.exit(1)` but do not give me argument.

Anyone stumble upon this before ?

Comment: What hook? There are [many](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks). What argument(s) do you expect? Some hooks have a lot of parameters and stdin, some hooks don't have parameters at all and get all information from the environment.

Comment: The pre-commit hook is another executable (usually a script) forked from the git process, and it takes no arguments. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is a pre-commit hook i forgot to mentionned it.
I am trying to get information about anything during this commit, changed file, git config (mail author).

Comment: [`pre-commit` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_commit) takes no parameters.

Comment: Then how can i get git config on a pre-commit hook. How can i access the changed files in order to check spelling mistake. I do not look for a framework i look to do it myself in order to learn.

Comment: `pre-commit` hook runs in the local repository. It has access to the working tree, to the repo, to its config, to the index (cache). Use the same commands you'd use outside of hooks.

Comment: Alright, i can get the git config by using `subprocess.run(["git", "config", "--global",  "--get",  "user.name"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`.
Is there a better way ? I don't think there is a command to read filed that are being commited or to read commit message is there ?

Comment: There are many. Just an example: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+python+get+commit+message